# If $0<A\le x_n\le B~~ (\forall n)$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}=A$. Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}=A.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

**Problem**

Assume $ 0<A \le x_n\le B~~ (\forall n)$, and $\displaystyle
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}=A$.
Prove $$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}=A.$$

Is it true or not ?

Probably it holds, but seems to be difficult to prove. If we consider using the squeezing theorem, then

$$\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}\le \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n},$$

but how to estimate the upper bound?

Comment: Also, what's $x_n$?

Comment: @Divide1918 Sorry, typos Edited.

Comment: This is a generalization of the Arithmetic-geometric mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean

Comment: @Lereu How does this comment help?

Comment: Source of this question? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: Here is proof on a Chinese website. Is it correct?

https://www.zhihu.com/question/628578500/answer/3273098039

Comment: @mengdie1982: If you have questions about some proofs found on a website then I would suggest that you post that as a separate question, with  a link to the website and a translation to English. Also make sure to ask a *specific question* and not just “Is this proof correct?” See https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info and the referenced Meta posts for more information about solution-verification questions.

Comment: Is the result still true if we remove the boundedness condition?

Answer (score 8):

It is easy to prove that, for $A \leq x \leq B$,

$$ x - A \leq B \log\left(\frac{x}{A}\right), $$

where $\log(\cdot)$ is the natural logarithm. Then

$$ 0
\leq \color{blue}{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k - A}
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (x_k - A)
\leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} B\log\left(\frac{x_k}{A}\right)
= B [\color{red}{\log\left( \sqrt[n]{x_1 \cdots x_n} \right) - \log A}]. $$

So, the desired conclusion follows from the squeezing lemma.

Comment: can you please explain how to prove that $$ x - A \leq B \log\left(\frac{x}{A}\right), $$

Comment: @pie, Set $f(x) = B\log(x/A) - (x - A)$ and note that $f(A) = 0$ and $f'(x)=\frac{B}{x}-1\geq 0$ for $x\in[A,B]$.

Comment: This is indeed an elegant argument! – One could also use the *concavity* of the logarithm to get the lower bound $\log(x/A)/(x-A) \ge \log(B/A)/(B-A)$.

Answer (score 8):

Fix a number $C > A$ and define
$$
 f(n) = \# \{ k \in \{1, \cdots, n \} \mid x_n > C \} \, .
$$
Then
$$
 p_n := \sqrt[n]{a_1 \cdots a_n } \ge \sqrt[n]{A^{n-f(n)} c^{f(n)} }
 = A \left( \frac CA \right)^{f(n)/n}
$$
and therefore
$$
 0 \le \frac{f(n)}{n} \le \frac{\ln(p_n/A)}{\ln(C/A)}
$$
Since $p_n \to A$ it follows that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = 0 \, .
$$
Then
$$
 \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \le \frac{(n-f(n))C + f(n)B}{n} \le C + \frac{f(n)}{n} \cdot B
$$
and since $f(n)/n \to 0$ this implies
$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \le C \, .
$$
This holds for all $C> A$, so that we get the desired upper bound
$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \le A \, .
$$

Comment: Here is proof on a Chinese website. Is it correct? zhihu.com/question/628578500/answer/3273098039

Comment: @mengdie1982: I do not speak Chinese. After a quick glance at it I have the feeling that it is a similar argument as in Sangchul Lee's very nice answer.

Comment: There are 2 proofs. How about the first one? If need, I'm willing to translate it to English.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\ 0 < A \leq x_n \leq B,\ $ and $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n} = A.$

Lemma: For any $\ \varepsilon > 0,\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ \left\lvert\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \cap [A, A+\varepsilon]\right\rvert }{n} = 1.$

Proof of Lemma: Let $\ \varepsilon > 0.\ $ Suppose, by way of contradiction, that it is not true that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ \left\lvert\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \cap [A, A+\varepsilon] \right\rvert }{n} = 1.\ $ Then $\ \exists\ \mu > 0,\ $ and an increasing sequence of positive integers $\ (M_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ such that $\ \frac{ \left\lvert \left\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{M_k}\right\} \cap [A, A+\varepsilon] \right\rvert }{ M_k} < (1-\mu)\quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ This implies that $\ \frac{ \left\lvert \left\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{M_k}\right\} \cap (A+\varepsilon, B ] \right\rvert }{ M_k} \geq \mu\quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ Thus we have: $\ \left\lvert \left\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{M_k}\right\} \cap [A, A+\varepsilon] \right\rvert < (1-\mu)M_k\quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{N},\ $ and $\ \left\lvert \left\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{M_k}\right\} \cap (A+\varepsilon, B ] \right\rvert \geq \mu M_k\quad \forall\ k\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ But then we have:

$$ \prod_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in [A, A+\varepsilon] }} x_i \geq A^{ (1-\mu)M_k }, \implies \sqrt[M_k]{\prod_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k} \\ x_i \in [A, A+\varepsilon] }} x_i } = \left(\prod_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in [A, A+\varepsilon] }} x_i \right)^{1/M_k} \geq A^{1-\mu}, $$

and

$$\prod_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in (A+\varepsilon, B] }} x_i \geq (A+\varepsilon)^{ \mu M_k }, \implies \sqrt[M_k]{\prod_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in (A+\varepsilon, B] }} x_i } = \left(\prod_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in (A+\varepsilon, B] }} x_i \right)^{1/M_k} \geq (A+\varepsilon)^{\mu}$$

$$ > A^{\mu} + \mu A^{\mu-1}\varepsilon, $$

where the final step uses [Newton's generalised Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem).

Putting these two things together, we get:

$$ \left(\prod_{i=1}^{ M_k } x_i \right)^{1/M_k} = \left(\prod_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in (A+\varepsilon, B] }} x_i \right)^{1/M_k} \left(\prod_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in (A+\varepsilon, B] }} x_i \right)^{1/M_k} \geq A^{1-\mu} \left( A^{\mu} + \mu A^{\mu-1}\varepsilon\right)$$

$$= A + \mu\varepsilon. $$

But since $\ (M_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ an increasing sequence of positive integers, $ \left(\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{ M_k } x_i \right)^{1/M_k} \geq A + \mu\varepsilon\ $ is true for infinitely many $\ k,\ $ contradicting $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n} = A.\ $ We have our contradiction, and so the proof of the Lemma is complete.

Now let $\ \varepsilon>0,\ \delta> 0.\ $ Since $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ \left\lvert\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \cap [A, A+\varepsilon]\right\rvert }{n} = 1,\ \exists\ N\ $ such that $\ \frac{ \left\lvert\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \cap [A, A+\varepsilon]\right\rvert }{n} > 1-\delta,\quad \implies \ \left\lvert\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \cap [A, A+\varepsilon]\right\rvert > (1-\delta)n,$

$ \implies \ \left\lvert\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \cap (A+\varepsilon, B]\right\rvert \leq \delta n\quad \forall\ n\geq N. $

Noting that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = \sum_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in [A, A+\varepsilon] }} x_i + \sum_{\substack{ { i \leq M_k } \\ x_i \in (A+\varepsilon, B] }} x_i, $$

we have:

$$ An \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \leq (A+\varepsilon)(1-\delta)n + B\delta n\quad \forall\ n\geq N $$

$$ \implies A \leq \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i }{n} \leq (A+\varepsilon)(1-\delta) + B\delta = A + (B-A-\varepsilon)\delta + \varepsilon \quad \forall\ n\geq N. $$

Now let $\ \varepsilon\to 0,\ \delta\to 0\ $ and applying the Squeeze theorem, we get the result.

Comment: I think some of my notation is comprehensible, but "dodgy", but I don't know how to do multiple lines underneath a summation or product sign.

Comment: We may have had similar ideas (considering the density of indices for which $x_n$ is close to $A$ or not)!

Comment: substack command didn't work for me when I tried a few days ago. But I'll try again now.

Comment: @MartinR thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity denote $y_i=\log a_i$, $C=\log B$ and without loss of generality assume $\log A=0.$ Consider the random variable $Y_n$ such that $\Pr(Y_n=y_i)=1/n.$ For all $a\in (0,C)$ we have
$$E(Y_n)=\int_0^C\Pr(Y_n>y)dy\geq \int_0^a\Pr(Y_n>y)\geq a\Pr(Y_n>a).$$ Since $E(Y_n)\to0$ then for all $a>0$ we have $\Pr(Y_n>a)\to 0.$ In other terms, if $\mu_n$ is the law of $Y_n$ then $\mu_n\to \delta_0$ for weak convergence. Therefore, since $f(y)=e^y$ is continuous on $[0,C]$ we have $E(e^{Y_n})\to f(0)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

When $x_1\leq x_2$ are in the interval $[A,B]$, if we keep the arithmetic mean of $x_1$ and $x_2$ fixed, the minimal geometric mean will be attained when either $x_1=A$ or $x_2=B$.  Of course this applies to any pair of the $x_i$.  Thus we can modify the $n$-tuples $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ while keeping their arithmetic means fixed, until all but one of the $x_i$ are either $A$ or $B$.  Of course a single $x_i$ in $[A,B]$ does not affect the asymptotic behavior of either the geometric or the arithmetic means, so we can assume that all of them are either $A$ or $B$.  Let's assume for simplicity that $A=1$ and $B=2$ (the general argument is similar).  Then we are reduced to the situation of an $n$-tuple of the form $1=x_1=\cdots=x_{n-k}$, $x_{n-k+1}=\cdots=x_n=2$.  Here the geometric mean equals $\sqrt[n]{2^k}$ which tends to $1$ if and only if $\frac kn$ tends to zero.  Similarly, the arithmetic mean is $\frac{n+k}{n}$ tends to zero if and only if $\frac kn$ tends to zero.  Therefore the two conditions are equivalent.

In particular, if the geometric mean tends to $A$, then the arithmetic mean similarly tends to $A$.