# Let $\left\{a_n\right\}$ be a bounded sequence of positive integers such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\left\{a_n\right\}$ be a bounded sequence of positive integers such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}=1$.Prove that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots a_n}{n}=1$.

Intuitively, I believe that when n is sufficiently large, $a_n$ is almost 1. However, I am unsure how to proceed with this problem. The condition of bounded positive integers is making it difficult for me to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $M\geq3$ such that $1\leq a_{n}\leq M$ for all $n$. Let
$f:[2,M]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$.
Clearly $f$ is continuous on the compact set $[2,M]$, so $b=\min_{x\in[2,M]}f(x)>0$
exists. In particular, $\ln x\geq bx$ for all $x\in[2,M]$. By $AM\geq GM$,
we have that $\frac{a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n}}{n}\geq\sqrt[n]{a_{1}\ldots a_{n}}$.
Therefore, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n}}{n}\geq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_{1}\ldots a_{n}}=1$.

On the other hand, by continuity of $\ln$. we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln a_{k}}{n}\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{a_{1}\ldots a_{n}}\right)\\
 & = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
For each $n$, let $\Lambda_{n}=\{k\in\mathbb{N}\mid a_{k}\geq2\mbox{ and }k\leq n\}$.
We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln a_{k}\\
 & = & \sum_{k\in\Lambda_{n}}\ln a_{k}\\
 & \geq & \sum_{k\in\Lambda_{n}}ba_{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\in\Lambda_{n}}a_{k}=0$
by sandwich rule. It follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n}}{n}\\
 & \leq & \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\notin\Lambda_{n},k\leq n}a_{k}\right)+\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\in\Lambda_{n}}a_{k}\right)\\
 & \leq & 1+0
\end{eqnarray*}
by observing that $a_{k}=1$ whenever $k\notin\Lambda_{n}$ and $k\leq n$.
In short, $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n}}{n}\leq1$.
Now, it is clear that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n}}{n}=1$
because $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ coincide and equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis $a_i$ integer is useless and can be replaced by $a_i\geq 1.$ Denote $b_i=\log a_i$ and consider the random variable $X_n$ with the following law: $\Pr(X_n=b_i)=1/n.$ Then for any $a>0$ we have

$$a\Pr(X_n>a)\leq E(X_n)\to_{n\to \infty} 0.$$ As a consequence the size of the set $S_n(a)$ of $i\leq n$ such that $b_i>a$  satisfies $|S_n(a)|/n\to_{n\to \infty} 0.$ Therefore for all $a$ using the fact that $b_i<B$ since bounded we can write

$$1\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{b_i}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i\in S_n(a)} e^{b_i}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i\notin S_n(a)} e^{b_i}$$$$\leq \frac{|S_n(a)|}{n}e^B+\frac{n-|S_n(a)|}{n}e^a\to_{n\to \infty}e^a$$ Since this is true for all $a>0$ this shows that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{b_i}\to_{n\to \infty}1$$ which is the desired result.

Comment: The question is a duplicate, and you  already answered the older question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4798426/42969.